# sqoop is not working as expected NULL Sting from source is populated as \\N

Tags: hive, sqoop, cloudera, hadoop2

I am trying to use null-string while pulling data from Oracle SQL Server
But for null value in SQL server while importing to HDFS I am getting **'\\N'** value and for which Hive table is also populated with **'\\N'** value .

I use as

```sh
sqoop --connect ABCD --username A \
--password B@123 \
--escaped-by \\ \
--null-string '\\N' \
--target-dir /user/anu/dear
```

But in hdfs I am getting as :
Anu,**'\\N'**,Boledion,12638

Expected Results :
**Anu,\N,Boledion,12638**

NB: I tried using **'\N'** - Getting Sqoop Java **error** saying '\N' cannot process or wrong escape .

And even tried **'\\N'** as mentioned in cloudera QnA
4 Slashed 
It is highly appreciated in I can get this solved.

Comment: Can you try

`-null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N'`

Comment: I have tried it but still same \\N in place of NULL or \N